# Ask for an algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I want to know what algorithm the following problem can refer to. I guess it can be represented in CSP but the actions are randomized.

Assume I am playing monopoly. I can choose either 1, 2, or 3 dice for movement in each round. My goal is to skip other players' buildings and also go to a specific range of grids. What is a good algorithm to

```
select number of dice in each round
```

subject to

```
1. minimize number of rounds
2. skip some grids
3. move to some grids
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 dice is a pretty small number, so brute force should work well. Assign a value to each square (maybe -$50 to a property with rent $50 if an opponent owns it), then compute the expected value of each roll (1/6 of each of the next six squares for 1 die, 1/36 of two squares ahead + 1/18 of three squares ahead + ... + 1/36 of 12 squares ahead, etc.).

Comment: with 18 possible outcomes per move for 3 dices, brute force is only a good idea, if  you only want to predict the next move

Comment: @Paul It's 16 possible outcomes. A 5 move lookahead therefore still only requires the evaluation of 1048576 positions. But you only have 3 possible moves either way, and you can probably prune the decision tree heavily.

Comment: And given that a standard Monopoly board only has 40 squares, looking too far ahead makes very little difference in the outcome.

Comment: @biziclop oops, my mistake. you're right - 18 moves.

Comment: Probability of the possible outcomes for three dice, in case anyone's interested: 3/18: 0.005, 4/17: 0.014, 5/16: 0.028, 6/15: 0.046, 7/14: 0.069, 8/13: 0.097, 9/12: 0.116, 10/11: 0.125. (all rounded to three decimal places).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need some sort of combination of A* or Dijkstra and MiniMax (atleast if you want have a better result than just what can be derived from the current state).

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign weighting (risk or priorities) to each of your constraints, and this depends on how risk averse you are. You would assign a positive value for a benefit and a negative value for a penalty. So, for example, element 1. would always suggest using 3 dice, but you need to assign a relative benefit for each of the 3 options. Then for the other 2 you would, for each choice of dice calculate the probability of landing on a beneficial grid and similarly a penalty grid, multiple these by your weighting, and add them all together, choosing the most positive outcome. But note that different weightings will give different answers. If you give option 1 an absurdly high weighting it will always chose 3 dice. Otherwise any outcome is possible.